# Finding 4 consecutive same value integers in an unsorted array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've looked all around but could not find someone who has done this in java for some reason. I need to make a section of code that takes an array of single spaced integers and determines whether or not there are four consecutive, same value, integers in it. (I've coded in other languages before but I am trying to learn Java so the fact that I cannot get this to work drives me insane.) I've included below what code I've written so far.

```
public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[] checkArray) {  

    for (int i = 1; i < checkArray[0]-1; i++){
        int lower2 = [checkArray[i-2] intValue];
        int lower1 = [checkArray[i-1] intValue];
        int mid = [checkArray[i] intValue];
        int upper1 = [checkArray[i+1] intValue];
        int upper2 = [checkArray[i+2] intValue];

        if ((lower2 == lower1 && lower1 == mid && mid == upper1) 
                                    || 
            (lower1 == mid && mid == upper1 && upper1 == upper2)) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: When you say “single spaced” what do you mean? Is the raw input a String?

Comment: Yea it's a String inputted by the user

Comment: *I need to make a section of code...* is the for homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What went wrong in your code?

The other answer shows you a quick and smart way to obtain your result directly from the user input. I’ll take a look at your code and fix the bugs.

You’ve got a syntax problem here:

```
        int lower2 = [checkArray[i-2] intValue];
```

The outer square brackets and the word `intValue` don’t belong here. Assuming that you have already put the user input into an array of integers (as the parameter declaration `int[] checkArray` says), you may just do:

```
        int lower2 = checkArray[i - 2];
```

Similar for the other assignments.

Next you have got some boundary condition problems. The first time through your loop `i` is 1, so `checkArray[i-2]` tries to take out an element at index -1. Array indices go from 0 and up, so this throws an exception. Instead start your loop from `int i = 2`. Indices goes up to one less than the array length. You get the array length from `checkArray.length`. Since you want to do `checkArray[i+2]`, you need that `i < checkArray.length - 2`, so let this be your condition in the `for` loop.

No, wait. Your third problem is not an error, just an over-complication of the logic: You are taking out five consecutive integers into `lower2`, `lower1`, `mid`, `upper1` and `upper2`. You needed only four. So not to make things more complicated than needed delete `upper2`. Now you only need `checkArray[i + 1]`, so you can and must allow `i < checkArray.length - 1`. Now you only need the first half of the `if` condition, which makes the `if` statement a lot easier to read and understand.

That’s it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case regular expressions are taboo for this exercise, try this for an array of integers.

- assign the first value to some variable `v`
- set count to 1.
- now iterate starting at 1 to the end of the array and increment count if the next value is the same as `v`.
- check if count == 4 and take appropriate action.
- otherwise, set v to that value and count back to 1 and continue.

At some point in the algorithm above you may want to save the start and ending locations of the series, or copy them to another array.

Comment: It has the definite advantage that when one day we want to check for 3 or 5 or 11 consecutive  equal numbers, the modification should be trivial (it’s also probably more efficient, but that should be of no concern in an exercise like this one).

Comment: @OleV.V  True.  My concern is that the OP is a student and they were supposed to use split or read them via a Scanner.  Regex is somewhat advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a string of single digits separated by spaces, use regex to do it in one line:

```
input.matches(".*(\\d)( \\1){3}.*")
```

`(\\d)` captures a digit as group 1 and `\1` is a *back reference* to group 1.

To match arbitrary length numbers that are separated by an arbitrary quantity of spaces:

```
input.matches(".*(\\b\\d+)( +\\1){3}.*")
```

---

Your syntax is a little off. Try something like:

```
int lower2 = checkArray[i-2];
```

Also your loop starts too early and ends too late.

Also, you are checking 5 numbers, but your question title says 4.

Comment: Delete your method and the conversion of user input to `int[]` entirely and replace with `boolean has4consecutive = userInput.matches(".*(\\d)( \\1){3}.*");`. Or edit your method as per the last part of my answer.

Comment: Ah yes that fixed most of it! I'm not really sure why I had it written in that way. I am checking for 4 numbers but the was I was doing it I was having it check for matching integers up two and down two.

Comment: I had to change a few things but It's working perfectly now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A regexp solution is impressive but the task may also be resolved for a decent array of integers, and it could be extended to find N consecutive numbers in an array.

Therefore, we can immediately define that no N consecutive numbers occur in an array with the length less than N, and also, if an unprocessed "tail" contains less than N numbers, we can finish earlier:

```java
public static boolean hasNconsecutive(int n, int ... arr) {
    if (null == arr || arr.length < n) {
        return false;
    }
    int prev = arr[0];
    int cnt = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length && cnt < n; i++) {
        if (prev == arr[i]) {
            cnt++;
        } else {
            cnt = 1;
            prev = arr[i];
            if (i + n > arr.length) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt == n;
}
```

Implementation using Stream API may look as follows:

```java
public static boolean hasNconsecutiveStream(int n, int ... arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length - n + 1)
             .map(i -> (int)IntStream.range(i, i + n).filter(x -> arr[i] == arr[x]).count())
             .anyMatch(x -> x == n);
}
```

Tests:

```
int[][] tests = {
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 4},
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4},
    {2, 1, 2, 1, 1},
    {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3},
};

int n = 4;
for (int[] t : tests) {
    System.out.printf("%d consecutive?\t%s,\tstream? %s\tin %s%n", 
        n, hasNconsecutive(n, t), hasNconsecutiveStream(n, t), Arrays.toString(t));
}
```

Output:

```
4 consecutive?  false,  stream? false   in [1, 1, 1]
4 consecutive?  true,   stream? true    in [1, 1, 1, 1]
4 consecutive?  false,  stream? false   in [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
4 consecutive?  true,   stream? true    in [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]
4 consecutive?  false,  stream? false   in [2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
4 consecutive?  true,   stream? true    in [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
4 consecutive?  false,  stream? false   in [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
```